# How to zoom out the entire website on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web

I want to zoom out my website when the screen resolution is on 1366*768
the website looks very zoomed-in when chrome is zoom on 100%

I tried

html {
zoom:80%;
transform: scale(1)
transform-origin: 0 0;
}

but nothing works.

Please any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this css code. It works with current versions of Chrome, FF, Safari and IE.

```
html {
    zoom: 0.8;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! the problem is fixed but i have a slider in the home page after i put the code it changes how i can fixe it

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/4Vp2fnW)  this is a link to see what happened

Comment: If you need center alignment change `-moz-transform-origin: center 0;` and add `transform-origin: center 0;`